# Attempt at fire jet peters out after a single puff

Tags: smoke-simulation, fire

(Possibly related to [Fire sputters out](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/174542/fire-sputters-out))

Hi all,

I'm trying to create a sustained jet of flame using Quick Smoke; I'm using most of the default options but I've set the scene gravity to zero and I've set an initial velocity for the fluid in the z direction.

With these settings, a single puff of flame is emitted and vanishes within the first few frames. (On the other hand, if I set the initial z velocity to zero and give it a normal velocity, I get a ball of flame expanding heartily for the duration of the simulation.) I've tried messing around in pretty much every way I can think of and nothing seems to help.

Does anyone know what's going wrong here, or what I should be doing instead to get the effect I want?

[image]
[image]